# discord bot is repeting 7 times

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

So I was making a discord bot for the first time. So I was doing well until the bot started ignoring the prefix. The command repeated 7 times in a row. It will do the command right just more than once.

```
const client = new Discord.Client();

const prifix = '?';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./Commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFiles){
 const command = require(`./Commands/${file}`);
 
 client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('wow it came on!!');
});

client.on('message',message =>{
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prifix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args  = message.content.slice(prifix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(command === 'ping'){
      client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);

  } if  (command == 'youtube'){
      client.commands.get('youtube').execute(message, args);

  } if  (command == 'poop'){
      client.commands.get('poop').execute(message, args);

  } if  (command == 'No'){
      client.commands.get('No').execute(message, args);
 
  }
      
});

client.login('this is fine i just remove it ');
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Aren't you running your bot 7 times on your machine?

Comment: What area of the code is looping 7 times? Also, are you only running your code once. If you have 7 difference instances of it running it may do that also.

Comment: yes you where right it was running 7 times thx.